# redirect user after form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to let the user be redirected to a different page once he/she clicks on the submit button.

```
function signup() {
    var postData={ "service" :$('input[name=service]').val(), "ent_id": $('input[name=ent_id]').val(), "name": $('input[name=name]').val(), "mail_address" : $('input[name=mail_address]').val(), "password": $('input[name=password]').val()};
    postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
    $.ajax({
             url: 'http://domain.com/api?service=security&action=signup&request=' + postData,
             type: 'GET',
        });
    return false;
}
```

I want users to be redirect to http://domain.com/success.html/ 
Here's the html:

```
    <form onsubmit="return signup()">
       Name:<input type="text" name="name">
       Email:<input type="text" name="mail_address">
       Password:  <input type="password" name="password" >
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
       <input type="hidden" name="service" value="wf" />
       <input type="hidden" name="ent_id" value="null" />
    </form>
```

Comment: return false might be your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user once the ajax request has been successfully made, just add the "success" jQuery callback and use `window.location.href`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'foo',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function () {
      window.location.href = 'success-page.html';
  }
});
```

Comment: foo?! what happened to "url: 'http://domain.com/api?service=security&action=signup&request=' + postData,"

Comment: @user3362364 I hope you are not trolling; That is just an example... Read my message, I wrote that you just have to add a new property named `success` on the object that you are passing to the `ajax` method.

Comment: i used a beforeSend since there was a delay in submit button. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a user to another page by setting window.location I believe.  The googles are your friend!

Comment: What's the point of posting "google it" on a question/answer website?

Comment: You could have just wrote `window.location.href = 'success.html';`

Comment: I didn't have the .href part down.  The point I am making is the solution we are presenting is widely available if you search for it.  Helping people is great, but we should also help people help themselves.

Comment: That's why a more useful comment would have been:

"You can have a look at Javascript native `window.location` methods, check the docs here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp "

Comment: I'm asking here because i already have a URL from GET. Therefore it became tricky to redirect to another URL. Hence, asked.

Comment: What do you mean a URL from GET?  You make an ajax call to a url, sure.  And then your wanting to redirect in the success I assume?  I'm not understanding the confusion.  Is where you want to go upon success dynamic? Or are you saying that the url you want to go to will be returned from the GET request?  If so the answer provided 'Nicholas Valbusa' with the success callback is more what your after